# Python: Optimising a list comprehension which compares two integers

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list comprehension that acts on two lists of integers. It acts like `itertools.product`, with a filter to discard elements which are equal in both and a comparison to order them.

The code is as follows:

```
to_add = [(min(atom_1, atom_2), max(atom_1, atom_2))
          for atom_1 in atoms_1 for atom_2 in atoms_2
          if atom_2 != atom_1]
add_dict = coll.defaultdict(list)
for k, v in to_add:
    add_dict[k].append(v)
```

The most obvious thing I saw when writing it is that there is no need to call `min` and then `max`. What I really want is `min` and the other one, but I can't think how to get rid of the redundant call to `max`.

I profiled it and got the following results, which are representative of 10x repeats (`read_amber.py` is the name of the overarching function call):

```
     62880808 function calls (62880792 primitive calls) in 14.746 seconds

     Ordered by: internal time

       ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
           19    6.786    0.357   10.688    0.563 read_amber.py:256(add_exclusions)
     16431524    1.625    0.000    1.625    0.000 {min}
     16431511    1.295    0.000    1.295    0.000 {max}
       842947    1.051    0.000    1.051    0.000 {method 'format' of 'str' objects}
       842865    1.031    0.000    1.557    0.000 {filter}
     16457861    0.838    0.000    0.838    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
            1    0.793    0.793    3.757    3.757 read_amber.py:79(write_to)
      8414872    0.526    0.000    0.526    0.000 read_amber.py:130(<lambda>)
      1685897    0.266    0.000    0.266    0.000 {method 'write' of 'file' objects}
        97489    0.142    0.000    0.142    0.000 {sorted}
            1    0.130    0.130    0.300    0.300 read_amber.py:32(read_from)
       247198    0.127    0.000    0.155    0.000 read_amber.py:134(data_cast)
848267/848263    0.042    0.000    0.042    0.000 {len}
            1    0.038    0.038    0.038    0.038 read_amber.py:304(update_exclusion_list)
       500352    0.028    0.000    0.028    0.000 {method 'lower' of 'str' objects}
```

Is there a way to get rid of one of the redundant `min/max` calls? Is there another obvious way I could speed up this snippet?

I've already tried using the `itertools` generators, but the list comprehension is faster. I also tried `sorted` and the necessary casts, but `min/max` is faster than that.

Finally, I'm new to using `cProfile`. Is it sensible to sort by `'tottime'`?

Comment: Whats the format of `atoms_1` and `atoms_2` -- just python lists?  numpy lists?

Comment: Is the intermediate list `to_add` actually required?

Comment: @jedwards Just lists. I didn't figure involving `numpy` was necessary for this.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary No, it's not, but I would have thought that it would add almost no overhead to put it in there. Am I right that the list comprehension would be fully evaluated upon starting the `for` loop anyway?

Comment: Well `numpy` isn't necessary, but it has some optimizations for long lists that can help speed up things.  And to your question, yes, the comprehension would be fully evaluated.

Comment: I could certainly cast it into a `ndarray`. I'll see if that provides any improvements as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about:

```
import collections as coll
import itertools

add_dict = coll.defaultdict(list)
for atom_1, atom_2 in itertools.product(atoms_1, atoms_2):
    if atom_1 == atom_2: continue
    (atom_min, atom_max) = (atom_1, atom_2) if atom_1 < atom_2 else (atom_2, atom_1)
    add_dict[atom_min].append(atom_max)
```

Or, if the extra assignments are an issue (I hardly think that matters):

```
add_dict = coll.defaultdict(list)
for atom_1, atom_2 in itertools.product(atoms_1, atoms_2):
    if atom_1 == atom_2: continue
    if atom_1 < atom_2:
        add_dict[atom_1].append(atom_2)
    else:
        add_dict[atom_2].append(atom_1)
```

Although this seems less readable.

---

**EDIT:** timeit results:

Looks this approach cuts runtime in half.

```
import collections as coll
import itertools

atoms_1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
atoms_2 = [2,4,6,1,2,3]

def old():
    to_add = [(min(atom_1, atom_2), max(atom_1, atom_2)) for atom_1 in atoms_1 for atom_2 in atoms_2 if atom_2 != atom_1]
    add_dict = coll.defaultdict(list)
    for k, v in to_add:
        add_dict[k].append(v)
    return add_dict

def new(): 
    add_dict = coll.defaultdict(list)
    for atom_1, atom_2 in itertools.product(atoms_1, atoms_2):
        if atom_1 == atom_2: continue
        (atom_min, atom_max) = (atom_1, atom_2) if atom_1 < atom_2 else (atom_2, atom_1)
        add_dict[atom_min].append(atom_max)    
    return add_dict

import timeit
print(timeit.timeit("old()", setup="from __main__ import old"))  # 20.76972103
print(timeit.timeit("new()", setup="from __main__ import new"))  # 10.9827100827
```

**EDIT 2:** timeit results -- longer lists, less timeit iterations

```
atoms_1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6] * 5
atoms_2 = [2,4,6,1,2,3] * 5

print(timeit.timeit("old()", setup="from __main__ import old", number=100000)) # 46.2878425701
print(timeit.timeit("new()", setup="from __main__ import new", number=100000)) # 21.9272824532
```